# Unexpected token 'server' in expression or statement

Tags: powershell, syntax-error

```powershell
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Execute\Testing\servers.txt"
$ServerList

$Header="FolderPath,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritedFlags,PropagationFlags"

Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $Output

Foreach ($Server in $ServerList) {
    $output = "\\C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Repositroy "$server.output.csv"
    Del $Output -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $RootPath ="\\$Server\C:\system.sav"

    $Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    Add-Content -Value "$Header" -Path $Output

    Foreach ($Folder in $Folders){

        $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }

        Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){

            $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags

            Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $output -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a malformed string literal on this line:

```powershell
$output = "\\C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Repositroy "$server.output.csv"
                                                --^
```

The `"` pointed out above should not be there.  I think you meant to write:

```powershell
$output = "\\C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Repositroy\$server.output.csv"
```

---

The double forwardslash at the start of the string might also be incorrect. Perhaps it should be removed:

```powershell
$output = "C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Repositroy\$server.output.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you that has helped me get past that but now I get: "cmdlet where Object at command pipeline position 1. Supply values for the following parameters: Filterscript:" It's not appearing as an erro more like a request so i am wondering if its asking for the actual server to be inputted or not? I am running the test in my VM so i dont know if that might be causing this because I only technically have 1 "server" can someone advice?